# Which Spanish-speakers, if any, say "¿Cómo estuvo tu día" in Spanish?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, conversación

I'm aware that you can say "¿Qué tal tu día?", and "Cómo te fue el día?", but the second phrase is really asking someone how their day *went*.

Maybe *¿Qué tal tu día?* is the exact same as asking someone how their day *was*, but *"¿Cómo estuvo tu día?"* seems like the most literal translation, so I wanted to ask: In what Spanish-speaking regions do people use the expression *"¿Cómo estuvo tu día?"* if any?

Comment: Common questions in Mexico: *¿Qué tal, cómo te ha ido?  ¿Qué me cuentas?  ¿Qué hay de nuevo?  Cuéntame tus noticias.  ¿Qué has hecho?*  I personally like to ask my son at bedtime, *¿Qué fue lo mejor de hoy?*  but I've never heard anyone else ask that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general inquiry I would use:

- *¿Qué tal (fue/estuvo/anduvo) tu día?*
- *¿Cómo estuvo/anduvo tu día?*

Note how *estar* and *andar* work in the same way here, and sometimes *ser* as well. In the second example I wouldn't use *ser* because *¿Cómo fue tu día?* sounds like you're asking for a description.

These two can also be used but they may have different connotations:

- *¿Cómo te fue hoy?* (sometimes suggests the other person had some important task or appointment ahead today, and you're asking how that went)
- *¿Cómo estuviste/anduviste hoy?* (sometimes suggests the other person had some ongoing trouble, such as an illness, and you're asking how they've been feeling)

You can sometimes substitute *el día de hoy* for *hoy*, but that sounds a bit more formal. In some places in Latin America people say *hoy día* (almost as a single word) for *hoy*.

Answer (score 6):

"¿Qué tal tu día?" is ambiguous as to the time being asked about. It could mean:

- *How is your day (going)?* (asked as the day is going on)

OR

- *How did your day go?* (asked at the end of the day)

In my country (Argentina), I've never heard "¿Cómo te fue el día?", which sounds ungrammatical to me. I very much prefer:

- ¿Cómo fue tu dia? / ¿Qué tal / Cómo estuvo tu día?

Notice that "cómo" will accept either "ser" or "estar", while when asking "qué tal" the verb "estar" will be preferred.