# How do you say, "How was your day?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales, conversación

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Cómo se dice "How was your day?"**

**Details in English**

I'm pretty sure I've got a good understanding of when to use "estar" and "ser."  What continues to give me trouble is when to use "estaba," "estuvo," or "fue," especially with topics found in small talk such as the weather and other daily topics.  Lately, I've been trying to learn more conversational Spanish and was wondering how to say something as simple as "How was your day?"  Oftentimes when I have a question about a past or imperfect tense, I'll formulate the same sentence using present tense and make assumptions about past tense from there.  In this instance, I would likely say, in response to that type of question:

> My day **has been** good/bad.
>   Mi día **ha sido** bueno/malo.

... especially if I were referring to the current day.  If, on the other hand, I happened to be referring to the day before, I would say, instead:

> My day **was** good/bad.
>   Mi día **fue** bueno/malo.

or, more likely:

> I **had** a good/bad day.
>   **Tuve** un buen/mal día.

Ordinarily, I would think that such phrases would be best expressed with the translations you see above for each and from this, I assume that "How was your day?" should be translated as

> ¿Cómo **ha sido** tu día?

or

> ¿Cómo **fue** tu día?

However, I wanted to check my assumptions with at least one other reference, so I searched for

> How was your day?

over on Reverso.  My search showed me the following translations (number of translations in parentheses):

> **¿Cómo estuvo tu día?** (92)
>   **¿Cómo fue tu día?** (56)

I glanced at the English translations for each to see if I could detect any difference in meaning through context, but there did not appear to be any.  If there really isn't much of a difference between these two versions and it is simply a matter of personal preference, do Spanish grammarians consider these two different versions as having different meanings?  And if so, what are they?

I often ask Spanish speakers or those who are fluent if there are any differences in formality between two different words or phrases.  I was going to ask that about these two versions of "How was your day?" but then I looked at [**the Reverso examples.**](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-spanish/how+was+your+day)  If they are an indicator, clearly there aren't any (differences in formality).  What do you think?

One last thing.  I was listening to a YouTube video a while back.  I can't remember the name of the video, but I remember someone saying something like you use "fue" if you're referring to yesterday and "estuvo" if you're referring to something in the more recent past (such as earlier that day).  This might then explain why I see more translations of "¿Cómo estuvo tu día?" because I think most of the time, when people ask this question, they're really asking for some sort of recap of what the current day has been like thus far rather than asking about the day before.  Thoughts?  Opinions?

As always, thanks in advance for your time and attention to this question.

**Detalles en español**

Estoy bastante seguro que tengo una buena comprensión de cuándo usar «estar» y «ser».  Lo que me sigue dando problemas es cuándo usar «estaba», «estuvo», y «fue», especialmente con temas se encuentra en charla como el clima y otros temas cotidianos.  Últimamente, he estado tratando aprender más de español conversacional y me preguntaba cómo decir algo tan simple como “How was your day?”  Muchas veces cuando tengo una pregunta sobre un tiempo en el pasado — pretérito o imperfecto — formularé la misma oración usando el tiempo presente y al hacerlo, puedo hacer unos supuestos sobre el tiempo correcto usar en el pasado.  En esta instancia, es probable que diría, en respuesta a ese tipo de pregunta:

> My day **has been** good/bad.
>   Mi día **ha sido** bueno/malo.

… especialmente si me refiriera al día actual.  Si, por otra parte, resulta que refería a anteayer, diría, en cambio:

> My day **was** good/bad.
>   Mi día **fue** bueno/malo.

o, más probable:

> I **had** a good/bad day.
>   **Tuve** un buen/mal día.

Normalmente, pensaría que esas expresiones se expresarían mejor con las traducciones que ven arriba para cada una y de ésto, asumo que “How was your day?” debe traducirse como

> ¿Cómo ha sido tu día?

o

> ¿Cómo fue tu día?

Sin embargo, quería verificar mis suposiciones con al menos otro referencia, así que busqué

> How was your day?

allá en Reverso.  Mi búsqueda me mostró las siguientes traducciones (número de traducciones en paréntesis):

> **¿Cómo estuvo tu día?** (92)
>   **¿Cómo fue tu día?** (56)

Miré las traducciones inglesas para cada una oración en español para ver si podría detectar aún un poquito de diferencia en significado a través del contexto, pero no vi ningunas diferencias.  Si no hay mucho de una diferencia entre estas dos versiones y es simplemente un asunto de preferencia personal, ¿consideran los gramáticos estas dos versiones diferentes por haber significados diferentes?  Y, en caso afirmativo, ¿cuáles son?

Muchas veces, pregunto a hablantes de español o a personas que hablan con fluidez, si hay algunas diferencias en formalidad entre dos palabras o frases.  Iba a preguntar esa pregunta sobre estas dos versiones de “How was your day?” pero entonces miré [**los ejemplos de Reverso.**](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-spanish/how+was+your+day)  Si ellos son indicativos de la lengua española en general, claramente, no hay ningunas (diferencias en formalidad).  ¿Qué creen ustedes?

Una última cosa.  Estaba escuchando a un vídeo de YouTube hace un tiempo.  No puedo recordar su título, pero recuerdo alguien diciendo algo como se usa «fue» si usted se refiere a ayer y «estuvo» si usted se refiere a algo en el pasado más reciente (como más temprano ese día).  Ésto puede explicar entonces la razón que veo más traducciones de "¿Cómo estuvo tu día?" porque creo que la mayoría del tiempo, cuando la gente pregunta esa pregunta, está preguntando realmente para algún tipo de recapitulación de lo que el día actual ha sido hasta ese momento en vez de preguntar sobre anteayer.  ¿Pensamientos?  ¿Opiniones?

Como siempre, gracias de antemano por su tiempo y atención a esa pregunta.

Comment: Qué tal estuvo tu día, but more idiomatic: Cómo te fue hoy en la escuela/el trabajo, Qué hay de nuevo Cómo te va.  You can vary it up: Hola, cómo estás, cómo te ha ido (but this has a broader time scope than just one day usually)

Comment: In addition to what I wrote in [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21707/14627), I would add that I routinely employ *"¿Qué tal hoy?"* (no verb). Most times there's no difference between all those expressions you found.

Comment: Suggestion, in general.  Is there some way you could find a conversational partner and/or a group where you'd have opportunities to chat informally with native speakers?  You can analyze the process of riding a bike in great detail, before getting on it, but that is perhaps not as useful as just putting on the knee and elbow protectors and getting on an actual bike.  When it comes to greetings, if you just start greeting and getting greeted, your brain will act like a sponge and then you won't have to think about it, the natural phrases that people use will just come out automatically.

Comment: I think you already have the level of knowledge needed to be able to contribute as a volunteer community interpreter.  I don't know about other countries, but many parts of the U.S. have a high need for volunteer interpreters for medical and legal clinics.  It is an extremely rewarding volunteer activity, and it is just now especially needed.  Just a thought.

Comment: ¿Cómo te fue hoy? seems to me more likely to be used in Mexico implying that the day has finished.

Comment: @Fabian - "How was your day" has this feel too.

Comment: @pablodf76 TY4 sharing w/us what you personally use. I find details like that very helpful.  I have a question for you, though, about _"¿Qué tal hoy?"_  In addition to being used as a way to ask, _"How are you?"_ I am assuming that it can also be used literally. When I can, I try to use examples from movies, and in _Rocky II_, Rocky, having mismanaged money from his match with Apollo, tries to find employment.  He goes up to a foreman who tells him [**this**](https://goo.gl/D4SRNr) and Rocky comes back with [**this**](https://goo.gl/pLaVJC).  Would _"¿Qué tal hoy?"_ be used in this context?

Comment: @aparente001(RE: Is there some way you could find a conversational partner ... )  To answer your question, I have dabbled in this recently and even before just recently, I was an exchange student to a Spanish-speaking country where I fully and enthusiastically committed to only speaking Spanish and being spoken to in Spanish for the duration.  I totally agree with you about just getting on the bike with things and not just when it comes to Spanish.  Sometimes easier said than done, however.

Comment: @aparente001 I find that if you’re not in a totally immersive environment, you tend to rely on the 1 or 2 phrases you happened to learn initially whether or not you ever fully took the time to know precisely what it was you were saying or the nuances of meaning each might convey. As my Spanish gets better, I’m becoming much more conscious of word choice and its effects and this inquiry here is just an example of that. TY4 the comment. It never hurts to remind anyone to "get on the bike."

Comment: @aparente001 TY4 the volunteering suggestion. I actually saw an employment ad for something similar the other day but kind of got the impression that the employer preferred native Spanish speakers whose English was decent enough to serve as interpreters.  I think this was in the field of education, though, not medical or legal.

Comment: @aparente001 Either way, TY4 the compliment on my Spanish. I just failed the DELE B2 (just the listening and speaking portions, but mainly the listening portion ... regardless, you need to pass all four for certification). Needless to say, my confidence in my Spanish-speaking abilities took a dip after that experience. If nothing else, your compliment has made me feel better. Perhaps the abilities of a volunteer don't need to be at the level that would be required for employment, so certainly something to consider.  Again, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @LisaBeck Yes, of course, *¿Qué tal...?* can be employed to mean literally "How about...?". It depends on the dialect, though. I'd probably use *¿Y qué te parece...?*.

Comment: @LisaBeck - I saw your question about "¿Qué tal hoy?" and I would suggest avoiding that combination.  In Mexico "¿Qué tal?" works great as a greeting, but you  might not get a meaningful answer, just as in NYC, "How are you?" is not taken as a request for an update about how one is actually doing!  I personally would go with some of these: Qué hay de nuevo, cómo estás, cuéntame tus noticias, cómo te fue hoy con (tal o cual cosa). // I don't know anything about that exam.  Puedes participar en La Tertulia cuando quieras para practicar in general.  También...

Comment: ... cuando quieras puedes invitarme a un Chat Room para contarme adónde quieres llegar con tu español. // Sometimes school districts are also looking for volunteer interpreters.  I would start with the public school registrar.  Just ask them to keep you in mind next time they need someone.  The primary need is for new registrants but sometimes for a parent meeting or an exam, too. // There's nothing wrong with applying for a job, the worst that can happen is they don't offer it to you.  You might be right, it might be easier to get a foot in the door as a volunteer....

Comment: ... if there's an organization that supports farmworkers or immigration documentation issues -- those might be good places to get connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como la mayoría de las respuestas que obtendrás aquí, depende enormemente del país. De todas maneras, creo que, aunque puedes decir "tu día", está más extendido "el día". De la misma manera que decimos "Lávate las manos" y no "Lávate tus manos", como cabría esperar de una traducción literal de "wash your hands".

También, en esta expresión solemos incluir un pronombre reflexivo, para indicar cómo fue **tu** día, y no el día en general. De manera que preguntamos "¿Cómo te fue?"

En Latinoamérica (creo que en general) y en algunas zonas del norte de España, el uso del pasado compuesto es prácticamente inexistente. En estas zonas casi siempre oirás

> ¿Cómo te **fue** el día?

Sin embargo, en el resto de las regiones de España, hacemos la distinción que tú mencionas. De manera que decimos **fue** si hablamos de ayer, y

> ¿Cómo te **ha ido** el día?

si hablamos del día de hoy.

Con tener, lo mismo: **tuve** para días precedentes y **he tenido** para el día de hoy.

Respecto al uso de **estar**, en España no lo usamos en ese sentido, pero está ampliamente extendido en Latinoamérica. Usaríamos "Cómo estuvo el día" de manera general, para indicar por ejemplo, el tiempo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: En lenguaje coloquial, creo que lo simplificaríamos a *¿qué tal el día?* Pero, en general, estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta.

Comment: *(...) el uso del pasado compuesto es prácticamente inexistente*. Como siempre digo, esto no es del todo verdadero. En Chile, decir *¿cómo ha estado tu día?* o *¿cómo te ha ido en el día?* resultan muy habituales.

Comment: Buenas respuestas de muchos aqui, pero creo que la respuesta de usted es la mejor en términos de la aclaración de ciertos aspectos de mi pregunta.  Nunca pensé que tantos responderían.  Aún así, sólo puedo dar una marca verde, y voy a darla a usted.  Gracias, María.

Answer (score 2):

As others already said, this can vary on the region/country, but at least in Colombia, these expressions are usual:

- ¿Qué tal estuvo tu día?
- ¿Cómo estuvo tu día?
- ¿Cómo te fue hoy? (No es una traducción exacta pero el sentido de la oración es el mismo).

Answer (score 2):

Para mí interpretar *how was your day?* corresponde simplemente a decir, idiomáticamente: *¿cómo te fue hoy?*

Algunas variaciones incluyen: *¿cómo estuvo tu día?*, *¿qué tal estuvo el día?*

Interpretar esto haciendo uso del antepresente, me llevaría a interpretarlo con dos connotaciones distintas:

> — *¿Cómo estuvo tu día?* (= el día ya terminó; mi día laborable terminó; mis acciones del día ya terminaron.)
>   — *¿Cómo ha estado tu día?* (= el día aún no termina; mi día laborable aún continúa; mis acciones del día siguen en curso.)

El uso del antepresente, al menos en Chile, es bastante recurrente y posee matices diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

### En Argentina:

> ¿Cómo te fue?

---

> ¿Qué onda tu día?

Answer (score 1):

I live in Argentina and here we say:

- ¿Cómo te fue (hoy / el día)?
- ¿Que tal (tu día)?
- ¿Cómo te va?
- ¿Cómo estuvo tu día?
- ¿Cómo va tu día?

In brackets optionals parts.

To answer you can be **very simple**:

- Bien.
- Hoy me fue bien.
- Estuvo bien.
- Me va bien.